# Bootstrap navbar - can only click the padding(?) of an image within <a> tag

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink, responsive-design, navbar

I have created a page using Twitter's Bootstrap framework; the problem is with the navbar.

I have 2 logos, each image is nested in an anchor tag. When the navbar is collapsed, the links work just fine, but when it is expanded (in the desktop resolution), you can't click on the image; looking at the elements in the inspector, it seems like what's happening is that the image is somehow sitting "on top" of the anchor tag, so that you can click in the padding around the image, but not on the image itself.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">

      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
      <a class="brand" style="padding:0px;" href="<?=getRequestProtocol()?>://<? echo curHost(); ?>"><img src="/images/HailStrikeGraphics/hs_header_logo_black.png" width="190px" /></a>
      <a class="brand" style="padding:0px;" href="http://www.stormdamagecenter.org"><img src="/images/nsdc_coin.png" /></a>
        <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
         <div class="nav-inner-wrapper">

           ...

         </div>
        </div>

       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
```

As this is my first post, I can't post screenshots, but you can see what I'm talking about here: [hailstrike.com](http://www.hailstrike.com)

This is clearly the result of some strange behavior with the way bootstrap is handling the resopnsive css, but I've been scouring the boards for a while, and haven't found a solution for this. Honestly I'm a bit stumped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the nav-collapse div is covering those links by taking up 100% of the width.

Throw your two logo `<a>` tags inside the `<div class="nav-collapse collapse">`

Add two `<a>` tags for your mobile site outside of that div, and use a class like `mobile-brand` with the same css.  I'd recommend you make them a little smaller as well.

Then add the following css to make them disappear when you're at desktop size:

```
@media (min-width:980px) {
  .mobile-brand {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked great! That was exactly what was happening. Seems like a bug for it to not be able to handle images correctly, since you're supposed to be able to add text to the logo area of the navbar and for it to be perfectly clickable. Thanks Alexander.

Answer (score 1):

Simply Add .customNav a.navbar-brand{position:relative;z-index:9;} it will sove your issue.